# Run request operations in loop inside operation

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

How can I run multiple requests inside the success block of 1 request and wait for it to finish?

```
[manager GET:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@ Response: \n%@", url, responseObject);
    resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *json in [responseObject objectForKey:@"items"]) {
        [self getDetails:json];
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; 
}];
```

Where in getDetails:(id)json is the method to load the group of requests whose parameters are based on the result of the main request.

For example:
I would like to request from the API a list of students, then on the success block. For each student, I would like to get the related data from another table (another request) and put them on my NSObject.

**EDIT** Here is my getDetails method

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)getDetails:(NSDictionary *)json
{
    NSLog(@"Start Op %@",[json objectForKey:@"related_salon"]);
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@read/salons/%@",SERVER_API_URL,[json objectForKey:@"related_salon"]];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
    //op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@",[json objectForKey:@"name"]);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed Op %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }];
    //AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];
    //op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op start];
    return op;
}
```

Comment: I am unsure of this, since I haven't really run operations serially, yet. Why not use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and queue operations in it's operation queue, adding dependencies for subsequent operations? This **might** give you serial execution (again, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

The AFNetworking `GET` method returns a `ATHTTPRequestOperation` (an `NSOperation` subclass). You could have your `getDetails` method return that object. You can then create a new operation dependent upon those operations, which you'd run at the end:

```
NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // add here whatever you want to perform when all the getDetails calls are done,
    // e.g. maybe you want to dismiss your HUD when all the requests are done.
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; 
}];

[manager GET:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@ Response: \n%@", url, responseObject);
    resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *json in [responseObject objectForKey:@"items"]) {
        NSOperation *operation = [self getDetails:json];
        [completionOperation addDependency:operation];
    }

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:completionOperation];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; 
}];
```

Again, this is presuming that `getDetails` is doing its own `GET` call, and that you change `getDetails` to (a) capture the `NSOperation` returned by `GET` and (b) return it.

Comment: How would my getDetails look like? Do I setup an AFHTTPRequestOperation and return it in that method?

Comment: Sure you could create your own `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and add it to a queue, or just do the appropriate `GET` request, which creates a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` for you, adds it to the manager's queue, and returns it to you. (Sorry, I assumed you already wrote that method.) The key is that just like AFNetworking's `GET` method returns the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to your `getDetails` method, your `getDetails` method should also return it back to the above code, so you can do things like establish dependencies.

Comment: I tried this method but I am getting a result of:
Operation 1 Success >
CompletionOperation Done >
Operation 2 Success

Please see edited question for my method getDetails.

Comment: That's probably because you're just calling `start` on the operations rather than scheduling them on `NSOperationQueue`. When dealing with operations, you rarely should just call `start`, but rather you should add them to an `NSOperationQueue`. By the way, your `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` has its own `queue` property, the `NSOperationQueue` to which it adds its own operations to. You could add your operations to that queue (or use the `GET` method, which will do that for you).

Comment: I have been able to resolve it but somehow the results are in reverse order (but this will do). Just a question, if adding queues to the Operation Manager seems to be a better way. How do I manually start the Operation Manager after doing addoperation WaitUntilFinished?

Comment: You don't "start the operation manager". Once you have your `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, it creates its own `NSOperationQueue` property called `operationQueue`, to which you can either do `[self.manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation]`, or use the `GET`/`POST` methods, which will automatically do that for you.